# How to update a cookbook that has been added to the Chef Supermarket?

Tags: github, chef-infra, cookbook

One of my colleagues added the [Sumo Logic collector cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/sumologic-collector) and made me collaborator.  I have since made updates to the [source on Github](https://github.com/SumoLogic/sumologic-collector-chef-cookbook) but can't find any documentation or any options or buttons in the Supermarket to update the cookbook from source.  Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Stove](https://github.com/sethvargo/stove) over `knife cookbook site share` if you are maintaining it as its own repo.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an account on the supermarket.  Then you can call `knife cookbook site share <cookbook name>` to upload it using your supermarket access key.